# Upgrade outdated linux production servers without shutting down

Tags: centos, debian

I came into some work with a client who wants to setup a monitoring infrastructure. The issue I have come across is a lot of servers are using really old kernel versions(from around 2012-2013) the monitoring system I am setting up requires a newer kernel version.

I am aware there is a solution where the kernel can be installer and reloaded in memory but this will still require that the system has a form of reset.

These servers are production servers and we cannot have them go down for any reason for any amount of time.

Also most of these servers are CentOS6 & 7 and a few CentOS4 and Debian8

What is my best route forward. What do other big companies do to stay up to date on their production servers?

Comment: Has your client got a disaster recovery plan in place? If not, it sounds like that is their first priority!

Answer (score 3):

100% uptime is not attainable. Their business continuity plan is not complete or realistic if they think it is.

Define what availability they are actually willing to pay for. As little as possible downtime means that multiple nodes are a necessity, such as a load balancer or cluster. Rolling upgrades mean the service stays available even when one host reboots. Which is a healthy thing to do, because it tests that the host can be restarted and come back.

To reduce the number of reboots of Linux hosts, implement live patching. Implementing and maintaining live patching requires considerable kernel release engineering effort. Such kernel updates are not available for free with CentOS. Look into subscriptions to RHEL or [KernelCare from CloudLinux](https://www.kernelcare.com/blog/resources/live-kernel-update-service-end-reboots-forever-with-a-single-command/).

Kernel live patching does not help for shared libraries used by everything. Especially libc. After a libc upgrade, you should restart all services, at which point might as well reboot.

Nor does live patching help end of life distros. CentOS 4 is dead, and a major upgrade is the  responsible thing to do.

Comment: The cluster idea is a good thought I will have to bring that up at our next meeting. The issue I see with that being they have around 500 servers that are running customer services if they were to setup a backup server for each of those it would quickly become a nightmare to manager. So would that truly be manageable? Alsio would like to note that this client has bare metal servers that host 50-60 vms on each bms.

Comment: A business continuity plan is far more valuable than any host. Review their most important services and what the plan is if they are down. Drill the basics like keeping software updated and occasionally rebooted. Show them options for HA such as clusters. Availability is not cheap.

Answer (score 2):

> What do other big companies do to stay up to date on their production
>   servers?

We have environments that allow us to reboot servers, the thing you're thinking of, probably ksplice, does work, to some extent, but you need a base OS with it installed and running already to be able to use it. Otherwise you'll need to reboot and/or rebuild.

Comment: Can you elaborate on `We have environments that allow us to reboot servers`

Comment: We use environments where no single server outage impacts service availability, by design.

Comment: See my comment on johns post and do you think that would be something manageable for us? I have thought about that I just do not see how that would be manageable

Answer (score 0):

what Chopper3 told you is correct. KSplice let you do that on some OS, I think it is Oracle Linux. For OS like RedHat and CentOS the tool is called KPatch.... There might be similar for Debian based distro, you will have to search...

That said, you need to have it prior the kernel update, so like Josehp said, youll need a reboot anyway. You may want to check the kpatch or ksplice doc.

Here is the DOC for RedHat https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2206511  .

Still, I think your machines OS revision/Kernel are too old for that... I would say, if it is possible for you, spin some new VM or pizza box and start from scratch/migrate to theses new machines. And unless you need to run legacy app, keep your kernel and distro up to date... For usability, but also for security.

Other wise, reboot you will need...

Also, what Chopperr3 was referring as ''his environment let him do that'' is that his application might be running in clusters or something like it, allowing him to reboot 1 or more machine at the time without affecting or having his application down.... (I suppose).....